# ScrollView padding without decreasing the scrollable area?

Tags: swift, swiftui

How can I make, that the Text get a frame around the scrollview so that the scrollable area doesn't decrease. If I would add padding around the ScrollView the small frame would not receive drags for the scrollview.

I have this layout:

```
struct ContentView: View{
    let width: CGFloat = UIScreen.main.bounds.width
    let height: CGFloat = 100
    var body: some View{
        HStack{
            ScrollView(){
                Text("""
                    test test test test
                    test test test test
                    test test test test
                    test test test test
                    test test test test
                    test test test test
                    test test test test
                    test test
                """)
                    .padding(.vertical)
            }
            .frame(width: width * 0.5)
        }
        .frame(width: width * 0.9,height: height)
        .background(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10).foregroundColor(Color.red))
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: What's the problem? `.padding(.vertical)` does already make the `Text` have padding _within_ the `ScrollView`. What exactly are you looking for?

Comment: I would like to have a sort of padding while scrolling. So that there is a red border around the scrollview without having a decreased scrollview. Perhaps I have to use a overlay

Comment: IMO you just need to make padding around ScrollView itself, instead of internal content.